# How to render a layer hosting NSView to file

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview, catextlayer

Is there any way to render a layer hosting NSView (as it appears onscreen) to a PDF or bitmap file *without* implementing each CALayer's `–drawInContext:` method (or similarly, each layer's delegate's `-(void)drawLayer:inContext:` method)? I just want the contents of the NSView exactly as they appear with minimal extra drawing code.

I've read numerous sources that say that to render to a PDF, you have to implement `-drawInContext:`, which makes sense if you're dealing with a custom layer subclass (otherwise, how else would it know what to draw), but I want to render layers that "just work" when you add them to a view, such as CATextLayer or CAShapeLayer. It seems completely redundant to have to rewrite the code for a CATextLayer telling it how to draw itself when it's clearly fully capable of doing that to the screen.

Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully written a view's layer hierarchy to a PDF using the following code:

```
- (void)renderToPath:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.bounds.size];
    [image lockFocus];
    [self.layer renderInContext:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext].CGContext];
    [image unlockFocus];

    NSImageView *tempImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    tempImageView.image = image;
    NSData *pdf = [tempImageView dataWithPDFInsideRect:self.bounds];
    [pdf writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

[Here's a sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/Render%20Layers%20to%20File.zip).

Comment: I'm so sorry... in re-reading my question I realize it was a bit misleading; this answer definitely works for creating a bitmap PDF, but is there a similar way to create a PDF that is purely vector (so `CATextLayer`s would remain selectable text, `CAShapeLayer`s would be resolution-independent, etc)? That's where `-drawInContext:` seems to be required instead of `-renderInContext:`, but I haven't gotten it to work. Do you know of a way to adapt this code for vector?